# Background processing with user-specific queues?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, background-process, resque, sidekiq

I've been using Sidekiq to process background jobs, but I'm finding it too limiting for my specific use case.

When users create an account, we import their data from a third-party service. That service has a rate limit so I can just thrown dozens of workers at it to speed up the import.

The problem is that I can't control the number of workers that granularly with Sidekiq.

I can limit the number of workers on a per-queue basis, but that doesn't help me here.

For example, if 10 people create an account, I have to rate limit the ENTIRE import of all the data for all 10 people but what I really need is to rate limit each individual account.

Practically being able to create a user-specific queue and then limiting the number of workers per queue would probably do the trick.

Is there anything like Sidekiq that allows for more granular control over the number of workers?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar situation where I needed to self impose a rate limit to avoid DDoSing an external service. I used [Sidetiq](https://github.com/tobiassvn/sidetiq) to control the queuing of Sidekiq jobs.

With Sidetiq you can periodically queue Sidekiq jobs. In your case you could create a Sidetiq job that, for example, adds 10 user import jobs into Sidekiq every hour.

```
class UserJobScheduler
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  include Sidetiq::Schedulable

  recurrence { hourly.minute_of_hour(0) }

  sidekiq_options queue: :default

  def perform
    # find 10 unprocessed user ids, then queue them up
    User.where(unprocessed: true).limit(10).pluck(:id).each do |user_id|
      UserDataImporter.perform_async(user_id)
    end
  end
end

class UserDataImporter
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  sidekiq_options queue: :user_import, retry: false

  def perform(user_id)
    # import user data & mark as processed
  end
end
```

I set retry to false in the class that actually called the API I needed to rate limit. This allows more precise control over the number of requests being sent. Otherwise failed requests will follow Sidekiqs retry schedule, which may be too aggressive for the service you are calling

You can then tweak the number of jobs added per run in the UserJobScheduler, and the frequency they are added to the Sidekiq queue with the recurrence setting to drop below the rate limit of the API you are calling.